# Issue with .htaccess file for R301 redirections

Tags: .htaccess

Good morning,

I changed the architecture of my website www.sirima.net, and I would like to setup R301 redirections from the old structure to the new structure, thanks to an .htaccess file.

Unfortunately, the .htaccess file below does not work. :-(

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/une_partie_d_elle.html http://www.sirima.net/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/bio/bio2.html http://www.sirima.net/biographie/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/bio/bio3.html http://www.sirima.net/biographie/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/bio/bio4.html http://www.sirima.net/biographie/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/bio/bio5.html http://www.sirima.net/biographie/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/bio/bio6.html http://www.sirima.net/biographie/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/bio/index.html http://www.sirima.net/biographie/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/credits.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/credits.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/index.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/sirima01.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/01-sometimes-love-i  sn-t-enough.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/sirima02.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/02-no-reason-no-rhyme.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/sirima03.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/03-his-way-of-loving-me.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/sirima04.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/04-kym.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/sirima05.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/05-a-part-of-me.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/sirima06.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/06-i-need-to-know.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/sirima07.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/07-ticket-to-the-moon.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/sirima08.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/08-i-believed.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/sirima09.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/09-daddy.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/disco/sirima10.html http://www.sirima.net/discographie/10-was-it-a-dream.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/hommage.html http://www.sirima.net/raphael-torr-ballade-pour-sirima.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/interviews/0003xx01.txt http://www.sirima.net/interviews/2000-03-la-bas-secrets-de-chansons-mars-2000.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/interviews/8711xx01.txt http://www.sirima.net/interviews/1987-11-ok-magazine-620-novembre-1987.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/interviews/880404.txt http://www.sirima.net/interviews/1988-04-top-50-109-4-10-avril-1988.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/interviews/891213.txt http://www.sirima.net/interviews/1989-12-ici-paris-2319-13-au-19-decembre-1989.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/interviews/8912xx01.txt http://www.sirima.net/interviews/1989-12-a-part-of-me-coffret-promo.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/interviews/9001xx01.txt http://www.sirima.net/interviews/1990-01a-paroles-et-musiques-25-janvier-1990.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/interviews/9001xx02.txt http://www.sirima.net/interviews/1990-01b-paroles-et-musiques-25-janvier-1990.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/interviews/index.html http://www.sirima.net/interviews/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/menu.html http://www.sirima.net/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/menu_texte.html http://www.sirima.net/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/merci.html http://www.sirima.net/merci.php  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/photos/index.html http://www.sirima.net/photos/  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.sirima\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.sirima.net/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: have you enabled `mod_rewrite` on your server?

Comment: Try to remove every leading slash in your rules and escape dots. Example: `RewriteRule ^/photos/index.html http://www.sirima.net/photos/ [R=301,L]` becomes `RewriteRule ^photos/index\.html http://www.sirima.net/photos/ [R=301,L]`